# Continuity of piecewise function involving defined by $f(x) = x\lfloor \frac{1}{x} \rfloor$ if $x \neq 0$ and $f(x) = 1$ when $x = 0$

Tags: calculus, continuity

Draw the graph and study the continuity of the function $$f(x)=\begin{cases} x\lfloor \frac1x \rfloor, & x \ne 0  \\ 1, &x=0 \end{cases} $$

Any help with how to solve something like that.

I am self studying calculus to prepare for engineering  and while I can deal with normal piecewise functions for some reason this one confuses me.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: For $x\geq0$ $\lfloor\frac{1}{x}\rfloor$ has discontinuities at $\frac{1}{n}$, $n\in\mathbb{N}_{>0}$. On the intervals $x\in ]\frac{1}{n+1},\frac{1}{n}]$ it is constant: $\lfloor\frac{1}{x}\rfloor = n$. Thus in these intervals $f$ goes linearly between $\left(\frac{1}{n+1},\frac{n}{n+1}\right)$ and $\left(\frac{1}{n},1\right)$. For $x>1$ $f(x) = 0$. What else do you need to know?

Answer (score 2):

You need to study
$$f(x)=x\bigg\lfloor{\frac{1}{x}}\bigg\rfloor$$

We know that $\lfloor{x}\rfloor$ is discontinuous at integers, therefore $\bigg\lfloor{\frac{1}{x}}\bigg\rfloor$ i.e $f(x)$ is dicontinuous at $x=\frac{1}{z}$ where $z$ is an integer.

Now at $x=0$,

$$\lim_{x\to{0}}f(x)=\lim_{x\to{0}}x\bigg(\frac{1}{x}-\bigg\{\frac{1}{x}\bigg\}\bigg)$$

$$\lim_{x\to{0}}f(x)=\lim_{x\to{0}}1-x\bigg\{\frac{1}{x}\bigg\}$$

$$\lim_{x\to{0}}f(x)=1$$

Therefore its continuous at $x=0$.

Here's the graph for the better picture,

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Discern the following cases:

- $x>1$ then $f(x)=x\lfloor\frac1x\rfloor=x\cdot0=0$
- $\frac1{n+1}<x\leq\frac1{n}$ for $n=1,2,\dots$ then $f(x)=x\lfloor\frac1x\rfloor=x\cdot n\in\left(\frac{n}{n+1},1\right]$
- $x=0$ then $f(x)=1$
- $-\frac1{n-1}<x\leq-\frac1n$ for $n=2,3,\dots $ then $f(x)=x\lfloor\frac1x\rfloor=x\cdot(-n)\in\left[1,\frac{n}{n-1}\right)$

Comment: Thank you for your answer.I dont really understand how when x>1 we end up with x ×0 =0.How is our first function different than x/x.Is there something in the notation that I am missing?

Comment: If e.g. $x=2$ then $\frac1x=0.5$ so that $\lfloor\frac1x\rfloor=\lfloor0.5\rfloor=0$ hence $f(2)=0$. Are you familiar with the floor function $x\mapsto\lfloor x\rfloor$? It sends $x$ to the largest integer that does not exceed $x$.

Answer (score 0):

write [1/x] as 1/x - {1/x} 
so you have x( 1/x - {1/x})
1- x {1/x}
x{1/x} limit is 0 as it very small multiplied by bounded
value. hence limit is 1-0= 1
hence contineous

i have discussed at 0.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Is this what the graph of $f(x)$ looks like?

(This should be a comment, but contains a graphic)